# How do I create a two toned color or watercolor look in illustrator or photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, texture

I am trying to create the two toned watercolor texture effect like the image found below.

[image]

I have tried unsuccessfully to create it using Photoshop and Illustrator.  Results I come up with don't effectively blend the colors like the example.

Comment: have you considered picking up a $5 watercolor, use paint, and then scanning it in?

Comment: I have in fact had some success with scanning real world watercolors, but hand art isn't really my primary skill.  I feel like the effect I see in the attached must be computer generated... I just can't figure out how.

Comment: I added a cropped image as you suggested, I tried to mark up the section of the picture that highlights the effect.  Apologize for low rez - I can create a higher rez if necessary - just trying to be quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really a 3 tone effect. If you want to easily recreate it in photoshop or illustrator, follow these steps:

1. Google search "Fee Vector Watercolor" or something similar
2. Use 3 different brush vectors, or flip horizontally and vertically so all 3 of them have different edges, and align them very close to each other on the site you want the effect.
3. Set the 2 bottom layers to 50% opacity and pick the 2 colors you want there.
4. Leave the top layer at 100% and set that as the color you actually want the body to be.

It is easy to do it this way, that way you don't have to worry about the two bottom colors blending into the right color on top.

Comment: I've got watercolor brushes and put the colors in different layers with varied opacity but cannot achieve the same texture. I suspect that there is some brush presets and layer style settings that make the difference but i have tried everything i can think of ...

Comment: You were right Case! I found some better brushes and played with the blending modes a bit, this was the end result here: http://imgur.com/x2jjb, not bad, eh? Still needs some tweaking but this is pretty close, THANKS!!

Comment: Glad to hear!!!